# Dynamic link in Gridview C#

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a grid view. Datatable is the data source.

I am looking for solution where I can add links to gridview column. But not by creating hyperlink field or not even want to play with designer part.

This is a common gridview, which will get dynamic data including columns.

Not necessary every datasource will have 'Name' column which is my target as hyper link.

I am able to generate  `<a href='...'>text</a>` but it is displaying as is in gridview.

**HTML block :**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCommonDashboard" runat="server">  

</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{                        
    string name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]);

    string url = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + listName + "/" + name;
     dr["Name"] = string.Format("<a href='" + url + "'>" + name + "</a>");

}
dt.AcceptChanges();                                     

gvCommonGrid.DataSource = dt;
gvCommonGrid.DataBind();
gvCommonGrid.Visible = true;
```

Comment: why you are not using hyperlink

Comment: you mean hyperlink field?

Comment: yea hyper link field or hyper link inside template field

Comment: I dont want to add another column, just need to modify the value of existing column from data source to be in link format

Comment: ok show your code html and code behide that what you are trying

Comment: HTML and C# code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the link in RowDataBound Event of the gridview -

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[CellIndex].Text);
        e.Row.Cells[CellIndex].Text = decodedText;
    }
}
```

Change the CellIndex to your actual cell index number.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the string using

```
string.Format("<a href='" + fullPath + "'>Text</a>");
```

i have tried this its works fine for me.